# how to move subfig label

Tags: labels

I have a list of subfigures inside the figure.   I am labeling them (a) , (b), (c)....
They have to be placed on top left corner of the image and on the image.  I managed to get on top left cornet of the image but I cannot move it up or down so that it can be positioned on the image.

```
 \begin{figure*}
 \captionsetup[subfigure]{position=top,margin={-3cm,1cm}}
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{image1.eps}}
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{image2.eps}}
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{image3.eps}}
 \caption{my caption here.}
 \label{myfigure}        
 \end{figure*}
```

I can move labels(a,b,c) to the left and right but not up and down on top of the image.  The command margin={x,y} does not move in y.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using `skip=` with a negative value, e.g., `\captionsetup[subfigure]{slc=off,margin={1ex,0ex},skip=-1.7cm}` ? It's hard to test what looks ok without access to the actual images. There are other methods (such as using the overpic package) discussed in the [subcaption documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf), section 7.

Comment: Is there some reason for using subfig instead of subcaption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the solution below

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom,skip=12pt}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{
  position=top,
  captionskip=1pt,
  singlelinecheck=false,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
  \hfill%
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
  \caption{Subfig}\label{fig:myfigures}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```